# UNION SELECT after LEFT JOIN and JOIN

Tags: mysql

```
    SELECT DISTINCT re.*
    FROM `reports` r
    LEFT JOIN `users` u
    ON u.`id_rep` = r.`id`
    JOIN `customers` c
    ON u.`id` = r.`uid`
    WHERE r.`uid` = '1' and r.`name` LIKE 'urgent'
    ORDER BY r.date DESC
```

Without making any modifications prior to the WHERE clause, would it be possible to use UNION (or a better approach) after the LIKE statement in order to SELECT from a fourth table called workers and ORDER the results BY `r.date` DESC?

Comment: I don't understand your EDIT.  Please make a stab at the query; maybe it will be clearer then.

Answer (score 1):

Using Union and `ORDER BY`:

Be explicit with results form first query:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT rep.name, rep.date as rdate
FROM `reports_new` rep
LEFT JOIN `repuser_new` ru
ON ru.`id_rep` = rep.`id`
JOIN `clients` c
ON c.`id` = rep.`id_client`
WHERE ru.`id_user` = '1' and rep.`name` LIKE 'urgent')

UNION
(SELECT username,rdate FROM users)


ORDER BY rdate DESC
```

I assumed the second table had a date column. Otherwise and explicit value could be used.

Comment: There's an example of that in the [manual page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

Comment: Try a new question. You're adding an amount of complexity beyond the initial question and without a full example with sample output clarification by comment is getting increasingly likely to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, yes.  Each of the following is OK, though not necessarily efficient:

```
SELECT ...
   FROM ( ( SELECT ... ) UNION ( SELECT ... ) ) AS x

SELECT ...
   FROM a
   JOIN ( ( SELECT ... ) UNION ( SELECT ... ) ) AS x ON ...

SELECT ...
   FROM a
   LEFT JOIN ( ( SELECT ... ) UNION ( SELECT ... ) ) AS x ON ...

SELECT ...
   FROM ( ( SELECT ... ) UNION ( SELECT ... ) ) AS a
   JOIN ( ( SELECT ... ) UNION ( SELECT ... ) ) AS x ON ...
```

etc.  (I may have added more parentheses than necessary.)

More UNION tips:

- Yes, the number of columns needs to be the same.
- The default column names come from the first `SELECT`.
- If you have a constant string in a column of the first `SELECT`, that limits the length of the matching string of the other `SELECTs`.  (Simply pad with blanks to 'fix' the problem.)
- If appropriate, use `UNION ALL` do avoid the de-duping phase, thereby being faster than `UNION`, which is the same as `UNION DISTINCT`.

Comment: @Rick the last 2 queries are equivalent. The `ORDER BY` is applied to the whole result set in both of them: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e7dc4fde39320da07f09ccec2ab90ca4

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - Geez, I'm only a decade out of step -- https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27848 "fixed" that in 2008 (5.0.56, 5.1.23).  Thanks for rattling my cage.